# How to create bins and assign labels based on a given condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe and I want to create a new columns (**new1,new2,new3,new4,new5,new6,new7,new8,new9,new10**) from the original columns(A-J). The condition is to create new columns by assigning bins to the values in columns (A-J).

bins to be assigned:

```
0
1.0 - 1.19
1.2 – 1.39
1.4 – 1.59
1.6 – 1.79
1.8 – 1.99
2.0 – 2.99
3.0 – 3.99
4.0 – 4.99
5.0 – 5.99
6.0 – 6.99
7.0 – 7.99
8.0 – 8.99
9.0 – 9.99
10.0+
```

DataFrame:

```
    A         B       C        D      E      F       G       H       I       J
0   34.00   5.18    19.10   70.00   0.00    1.10    3.30    2.96    0.00    1.45
1   3.65    7.20    0.00    3.15    14.00   0.00    8.20    13.50   0.00    0.00
2   6.60    12.00   104.94  3.60    24.00   6.54    23.00   4.83    0.00    0.00
3   2.16    5.30    0.00    8.40    31.48   0.00    6.40    26.44   0.00    0.00
4   4.66    268.86  160.00  19.14   1.58    17.77   47.57   88.01   0.00    0.00
5   7.40    2.64    0.00    4.90    3.53    0.00    46.00   0.00    0.00    0.00
6   6.18    60.00   8.06    13.50   6.20    3.05    9.00    38.90   0.00    0.00
7   6.51    5.30    6.20    17.00   27.00   15.00   4.51    11.50   0.00    0.00
8   3.25    40.72   4.37    8.02    0.00    110.00  16.25   3.95    75.00   0.00
```

The new columns to be added to the Dataframe should have the form.
Expected Output form

```
new1          new2     new3  new4      new5    new6       new7      new8     new9   new10

10+         5.0–5.99   10+   10+       0.00   1.0-1.19  3.0–3.99    2.0–2.99  0.00  1.4–1.59
3.0–3.99    7.0–7.99  0.00  3.0–3.99   10+    0.00      8.0 – 8.99  10+ 0.00  0.00  0.00
```

I tried to create the new DataFrame by using the **pd.cut** function in pandas, and also assign labels to this bin. but the number of bins created was up to 30 instead of 15. I also tried to assign labels to the bin but I get an error in the process

```
labels = ['0','1.0 - 1.19' ,'1.2 – 1.39','1.4 – 1.59', '1.6 – 1.79','1.8 – 1.99','2.0 – 2.99','3.0 – 3.99','4.0 – 4.99','5.0 – 5.99',\
          '6.0 – 6.99','7.0 – 7.99','8.0 – 8.99','9.0 – 9.99','10.0+']
bins = [0,1.0,1.19,1.2,1.39,1.4,1.59,1.6,1.79,1.8,1.99,2.0,2.99,3.0,3.99,4.0,4.99,5.0,5.99,6.0,6.99,7.0,7.99,8.0,8.99,9.0,9.99,10.0,np.inf]

df[['new1','new2','new3','new4','new5','new6','new7','new8','new9','new10']] = \
                          df[['A', 'B', 'C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']].apply(lambda x: \
                         pd.cut(x,bins),axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.cat.add_categories([0.00])).fillna(0.00)
```

`ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution involves editing your `bins` list:

```
# Same labels as yours
labels = ['0', '1.0 - 1.19', '1.2 – 1.39', '1.4 – 1.59', '1.6 – 1.79', 
          '1.8 – 1.99', '2.0 – 2.99', '3.0 – 3.99', '4.0 – 4.99', '5.0 – 5.99', 
          '6.0 – 6.99', '7.0 – 7.99', '8.0 – 8.99', '9.0 – 9.99', '10.0+']

# Define the edges between bins
bins = [0, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 
        5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, np.inf]

# pd.cut each column, with each bin closed on left and open on right
res = df.apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False))

# rename columns and print result
res.columns = [f'new{i+1}' for i in range(df.shape[1])]

print(res)

         new1        new2        new3        new4        new5        new6        new7        new8   new9       new10
0       10.0+  5.0 – 5.99       10.0+       10.0+           0  1.0 - 1.19  3.0 – 3.99  2.0 – 2.99      0  1.4 – 1.59
1  3.0 – 3.99  7.0 – 7.99           0  3.0 – 3.99       10.0+           0  8.0 – 8.99       10.0+      0           0
2  6.0 – 6.99       10.0+       10.0+  3.0 – 3.99       10.0+  6.0 – 6.99       10.0+  4.0 – 4.99      0           0
3  2.0 – 2.99  5.0 – 5.99           0  8.0 – 8.99       10.0+           0  6.0 – 6.99       10.0+      0           0
4  4.0 – 4.99       10.0+       10.0+       10.0+  1.4 – 1.59       10.0+       10.0+       10.0+      0           0
5  7.0 – 7.99  2.0 – 2.99           0  4.0 – 4.99  3.0 – 3.99           0       10.0+           0      0           0
6  6.0 – 6.99       10.0+  8.0 – 8.99       10.0+  6.0 – 6.99  3.0 – 3.99  9.0 – 9.99       10.0+      0           0
7  6.0 – 6.99  5.0 – 5.99  6.0 – 6.99       10.0+       10.0+       10.0+  4.0 – 4.99       10.0+      0           0
8  3.0 – 3.99       10.0+  4.0 – 4.99  8.0 – 8.99           0       10.0+       10.0+  3.0 – 3.99  10.0+           0
```

##### Explanation

The sequence of scalars passed as `bins` to `pd.cut()` "defines the **bin edges** allowing for non-uniform width": https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html.

By default, each bin is open on the left and closed on the right. To switch this, pass `right=False` (which also closes the left edge of each bin).

For example, `bins=[0, 1.0, 1.19, 1.2]` causes `pd.cut` to make 3 intervals: `[0.0, 1.0) < [1.0, 1.19) < [1.19, 2.0)`.